# Avoid Dependency cycles in Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, autofac

C# Windows Form application.
I have an Hub and a class. Both should reference each other.
This is because:

1. from the hub I need to call the class' methods
2. from the class I need to retrieve my Hub

Right now I'm able to do the first point using Autofac:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using MyProject.Classes;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProject
{
    static class Program
    {
        static IDisposable webApp;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            webApp = WebApp.Start(url);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Engine());
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var config = new HubConfiguration();
            builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterType<Erp>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.MapSignalR(config);
        }
    }
}
```

here the Hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using MyProject.Classes;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Hubs
{
    public class LiveHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly Erp _erp;

        public LiveHub(Erp erp)
        {
            _erp = erp;
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            _erp.someMethod();
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }
}
```

and here Erp.cs:

```
public class Erp
{
    public Erp()
    {
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // usually I do:
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<LiveHub>();
        hub.Clients.All.foo();
    }
}
```

but [here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html) I read:

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the GlobalHost. In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch. You should not reference GlobalHost anywhere when using the OWIN integration. Microsoft has documentation about this and other IoC integration concerns here.

If I cannot use the "old" method, how should I retrieve my Hub?
I tried to add another DI in Erp for LiveHub but it doesn't work. In my form I create an instance of Erp:

```
public partial class Engine : Form
{
    private Erp _erp = new Erp();

    public Engine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

if I add that DI the declaration will be impossible because I need to define the LiveHub in constructor, that requires itself the Erp parameter...

What am I not seeing?

Comment: So your `LiveHub` depends on the `Erp` and Erp on the LiveHub, is that it? What are the lifetimes of each? That can be avoided usually, i.e. the design issue. If you do need to go that way then one takes the .ctor parameter (DI-ed) and another gets the property injected. You'd normally need to set one w/o the `PropertiesAutowired` (and only DI through .ctor) and the other one to use the property injection.

Comment: ...and to add, the lifetimes are important in that case, as one is usually the singleton which is injected into constructor, while the other one is delayed injected as a property into that singleton.

Comment: I need `Erp` with as singleton (or say lifetime scope) because it receives and sends data from I/O devices. Then, when a client connects, it should send and receive data from them. From `Erp` I need the hub only to call clients' methods. From `LiveHub` I need `Erp` only to call its methods when clients request. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: lifetime scope makes sense if you have scopes that are created, torn down, if you define it globally that's effectively a singleton (but not sure of your details, just saying). Design wise that is not the best way to do it, though I understand your motivation. Always strive to have specialized services. In this case Erp should handle clients both in and out. To do that you could use events (I'd personally use Rx, Reactive events) to raise that from the Hub and Erp watching for it and doing its thing.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a solution to handle both direction from `Erp` but I didn't find. As far as I understand, you hint is very similar to @Bob van H solution (i.e. using events instead of (DI).

Comment: About events, the problem is the subscription will not work anymore when a new client connects, because a new instance of the hub is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decouple the `Hub` from the object (`Erp` in your case) by emitting events.

```
namespace MyProject.Hubs
{
    public class LiveHub : Hub
    {    
        public event Action SomethingHappened;

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            SomethingHappened?.Invoke();
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can connect the `Erp` without the Hub having to know it. You will have to subscribe to the event somewhere else in your code. But the circular reference is broken.

To decouple Engine from `Form` you could do something like this:

```
public partial class EngineForm : Form
{    
    public EngineForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Engine
{
    public Engine(EngineForm form, Erp erp)
    {
        this.form = form;
        this.erp = erp;
    }

    // Here is where you'll write some code to coordinate
    // communication between the Erp and the EngineForm. 
    //
    // The main advantage is that you can inject the Erp 
    // and have it preconfigured.
}
```

Comment: But from `Erp` I still need to retrieve the *current* instance of the hub. If I create a new one, of course the event is never catch. And the hub is created each time a client requires it.

Comment: Could you inject the hub into the `Erp` class? And the from there subscribe to the events?

Comment: Ok I see that you have the `Engine` class extending `Form`. This prevents you from injecting the `Erp`. It might help if you can make an `Engine` that requires a `Form` and an `Erp` to be injected.

Comment: Feel free to update you answer with an example of how to do that, if you don't mind to.

Comment: Ok I think I've solved the other way round. I kept the DI of `Erp` in `LiveHub` but I fire the events from `Erp`. In this way I easily subscribe to them in the constructor of the hub. I'm not sure if I need to remove them on disposing.

Comment: Good to hear you've found your way out. I'm still not sure about the role of 'Erp'. But I hope you got some helpful suggestions.